# Desktop bigger than screen

Tags: intel-graphics, display-resolution

My desktop has an inch cut off on the bottom and right side.

This is not a resolution problem -- changing the resolution only makes the text blockier. (so xrandr doesn't work)

I need to somehow resize the desktop to fit my monitor. It's natively 1400 by 900, but it thinks the screen is 1680 by 1050 (so it cuts off 280 pixels on the right and 150 on the bottom).

I did not install any new video drivers or anything. I think I'm running an intel 950 GMA chipset.

xrandr incorrectly reports in the second line: LVDS1 connected primary 1680x1050 -> this should be 1400x900

Do anyone have any ideas? thanks

Comment: xrandr incorrectly reports in the second line:
LVDS1 connected primary 1680x1050 -> this should be 1400x900

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: desktop resolution was way bigger than my screen. After reading [this ubuntu wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution) I fixed the problem just by changing the resolution with a command like this: `xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1024x768` (you'll have to change the output and resolution to your needs)

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if this solution will work for everyone, but it seemed to work for me.

Basically I ran a bunch of videos on VLC and the nytimes for a while until my computer fan turned on high, then reboot. The problem fixed itself. Maybe running a lot of videos does something to remind the computer what the right size is?

I don't know, but anyway, if I check `xrandr --verbose` before and after, all the weird monitor configurations were gone after the monitor resized itself. Go figure.